# Behavior of Flink Kinesis Producer when the destination stream is in UPDATING state due to UpdateShardCount

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

Quoting from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kinesis.html#kinesis-producer

> In case of a failure or a resharding, data will be written again to
>   Kinesis, leading to duplicates. This behavior is usually called
>   “at-least-once” semantics.

1. How can one determine how many messages are going to be replayed when the destination kinesis stream is in Updating state due to resharding?
2. How can one restrict the number of messages being replayed in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In case of failures, data is replayed from the last successful checkpoint. I'd imagine that it is similar for resharding.

To keep the numbers of duplicates low, you want to have frequent checkpointing (can go as low as 100 ms). If you use big (custom) state (as seen in the checkpoint size in Flink UI), you should use incremental checkpointing.